# Glitch with the red dot on the Review icon

Tags: bug, reviewing

Since cracking the 1000 rep level, I've noticed that the red dot that sometimes appears over the Review Queue icon in the top menu is lighting up when there are no posts to review. I mean there is nothing in JSE nor the JSE Meta to review.

This must be a glitch of some description, because I can't imagine a good reason to design this false positive alert.

Is anybody seeing this too? Can mods ask to have this fixed up?

[image]

And for the record, I am not performing any recent review Skips or maxing out my daily review limits.

Comment: This happens to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not noticed this bug for a while now, so I will assume that this has been quietly squashed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've seen this happen before.

The only thing I can think of is you have have skipped a review item and it may be cached or something. Either that or you just need to force refresh the page

If the problem still occurs, post a question on StackExchange Meta and one of the developers will probably get back to you

Comment: For the record, this still happens all the time and on multiple devices.  The red dot appears, I check, there is nothing to review.  Annoying.  I recall leaving a comment on a pre-existing Stack Exchange post, but nothing seems to have transpired.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Think it happened to me just now but I had JSE open on multiple tabs. Again, this isn't really the place to ask as nobody from JSE can fix this.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Ahh yes, it definitely just happened for me now

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304437/im-seeing-red-dots-everywhere/304442#comment1047244_304442